# Metal box above water heater

Tags: electrical

[image]

Morning ! Does anyone know what this is? It’s above the water heater in our garage  and I just noticed it has a black mark that looks like it was left by smoke. Thank you all!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That device shown in your picture is a small transformer mounted on an electrical box cover. Inside the electrical box the input side of the transformer is connected to the AC mains lines. The output side of the transformer provides a safe low voltage of 24VAC that connects to those small gauge wires that look to be brown and white/brown in color.

The most likely usage is that this 24VAC feeds power to a door bell setup. There are also other usages for a 24VAC transformer such as this. This could include a special thermostat setup, a security camera setup, a sprinkler control system or even a low voltage lighting application.

Comment: Thank you so much, Michael for your time and your answer. Should we be concerned about the light black mark coming from it that is going up the wall?

Comment: @PamT - It is hard to tell just what that slight discoloration really is. If it just washes off easily with a damp rag it could just be dust/dirt accumulation that has resulted from circulating air flowing around the transformer.

Comment: Awesome!!! Thank you again!! You’ve been super helpful!

Comment: Hi, PamT, and welcome to Stack Exchange. I agree with MichaelK. The faint "soot" is likely from dust-laden air rising from the warm transformer, and isn't a concern. (If Michael answered you well, please mark it as the correct answer by checking the big checkmark icon.)